# Menu (links) doesn't work on error page ...?

Tags: html, css

An error page > [www.marijevijselaar.nl/txp/oops](http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/txp/error)

Only the links in the menu aren't working anymore. The links in the footer are ok. I'm working in the latest Chrome (Mac).

CSS (only for #error404) >

```
html, body {  
    height: 100%;
}
#error404 #container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
#error404 #header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    background: transparent;
}
#error404 #footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#error404 #left {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    bottom: 180px;
    background: transparent;
}
#error404 #main {
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    right: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 190px;
    bottom: 180px;
}
#error404 #right {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    bottom: 180px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

It has to do with `html, body {height: 100%;}` ... because when you skip it the page is interactive again ... but then I've lost the background (opacity) on the #container (css elswhere in .ccs file).

Comment: Thanks all for responding. I'll look into it coming days. Happy Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

```
GET http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/txp/jquery.fancybox/jquery.easing.1.3.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Seems you've got a broken link. Using the developer tools in Chrome would have shown you this immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Your empty right `<div>` is on top of your left `<div>` which contains the links.

In that page, simply hide the `<div id="right">` using CSS or even inline style and your links will work again.

Another option is to set the `z-index` of the left div to be greater than the right div.

Comment: Still ... it's strange that the layout of the other pages with exact width for #left, #main and #right line up correctly. How come they break in the error page?

Comment: @redfox - Didn't look too deep, maybe because they're floating though.

Answer (score 0):

you've got an element overlapping the links, I noticed it when looking at in with dev tools open. when the bottom disclaim/copyright box overlaps the links, and there is a small space at the bottom, they work.

try removing `<div id="right">&nbsp;</div>`

change
`#error404 #right {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    bottom: 180px;
    background: transparent;
}`

to
`#error404 #right {
    display: none;
}`

and you'll see what's going on

Comment: I didn't reckon with an overlapping because the grid works fine in other pages ... #left, #main and #right all have exact widths ... so what's happening here?

Comment: I guarantee that it is an overlapping element